# How to select a default value from a dropdown list based on selected value from another list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

In my Symfony project when I select an Employee from an 'Employee' dropdown list, I need to get a default value from another dropdown list, 'Department' that Employee is in.

Both dropdown lists, Employee and Department are already populated from the database.

I have a form in Symfony where I can manually select an Employee and a Department.

How is it possible to get an employee's default department on selecting an employee's name from a dropdown list?

In the FormType.php file I have:

```
class CommMemberType extends AbstractType

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder
    ->add('employee','entity', array(
            'label' => 'Employee Name',
            'empty_value' => ' ',
            'class' => 'CompanyBundle:Employee',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.fname', 'ASC');
            },
        )
    )

    ->add('dept', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Department',
        'empty_value' => '---Select Department---',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'CompanyBundle:Lookup\Dept',
        'property' => 'meaning',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('dept')
                ->orderBy('dept.meaning', 'ASC');
        },
    ));
```

I also have a jQuery code and I tested just the console.log part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body .employee').on('change', function(){
    var id =  $(this).val();
    console.log(id);

    $.post('{{ emp_jquery }}', { 'employee': id },function(data){
        $('.dept').html(data);
    },"text");
})
});
```

Could you please give me a hand? Thank you so much!

Comment: You better start with forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html . You should add your class (with "attr") to the "select" input and style it on the front.

Comment: I have a form built where I already have the two dropdown lists. The Form works fine. I read that documentation, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, share your code and write a more explained description and "we"'ll try to help you.

Comment: I just added the code that I've written to solve the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As I understand, each employee belongs to one department, and you want to show it by default. Am I right?

Comment: if `.dept` is a select it's not like that how you select an option in jquery, Add your twig file and I'll post an answer that may help you

Comment: I just added the twig file. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `Dept` entity as a parameter in the form constructor and then use 'data':

```
class CommMemberType extends AbstractType 
{
    private $dept;

    function __construct(Dept $dept = null)
    {
        $this->dept = $dept
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('employee','entity', array(
            'label' => 'Employee Name',
            'empty_value' => ' ',
            'class' => 'CompanyBundle:Employee',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.fname', 'ASC');
                },
            ) 
        )

        ->add('dept', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Department',
            'empty_value' => '---Select Department---',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'CompanyBundle:Lookup\Dept',
            'property' => 'meaning',
            'data' => $this->dept ? $this->dept->getMeaning() : null, // e.g.
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('dept')
                    ->orderBy('dept.meaning', 'ASC');
            },
        ));

   ....
```

The, in the controller, you should pass the Department object to the form as a parameter: